# Is there a people picker view controller that works with Facebook friends?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm looking for an existing view controller like ABPeoplePickerNavigationController that instead of showing contacts from an address book shows a user's Facebook friends.

I've created a custom picker before but after seeing Words with Friends do something like the people picker, it seems like a better solution... but I don't know if they created their picker from scratch nor can I find anything out there.

Comment: I think I would wait a week before doing any more work on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't any open source libraries/frameworks that supply this functionality. You would just have to roll your own, may be a cool idea to open source it as well.

I can see people using such a thing.

**UPDATE**: After your new find, I do see `KNMultiItemSelector` does have the Facebook friend picker functionality.

[KNMultiItemSelector](https://github.com/kentnguyen/KNMultiItemSelector)

Comment: Yeah maybe I will but Kendall's comment is intriguing... What does he know!?

Comment: The timing is uncanny but this just popped up in my feed from Cocoa Controls: https://github.com/kentnguyen/KNMultiItemSelector ... I will try it out and report back here.

Comment: Great ! Looks perfect, I updated my Answer so if you wan't you can mark it as the Answer. =) Great Find !

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/kentnguyen/KNMultiItemSelector ...

The demo includes loading your Facebook friends...

Seems perfect!